# Beginner at HTLM5 - How to Create Horizontal Navigation Bar

Tags: html, colors, center, navbar, underline

I need a horizontal navigation bar with the words "HOME", "DRAWINGS", "STORE", and "CONTACT" evenly spread across the page. Right now my CSS looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
ul{
width:100%;
margin:0;
height:35px;
font-size:16px;
color:black;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
display:inline;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
}

-->
</style>
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="home.asp">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="Work.asp">DRAWINGS</a></li>
<li><a href="store.asp">STORE</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is what the web page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD7kt.jpg

Obviously I would also like to get rid of the underline and I need the text to be in black. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the li elements to float:left..

Like

```
ul{
width:100%;
margin:0;
height:35px;
font-size:16px;
color:black;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
display:inline;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;       
}
ul li {
 float:left;   
    margin-right:15px;
}
ul li:last-of-type {
    margin-right:0px;
}
}
```

Comment: regarding having the text in black and removing the underline, the elements inherit the default link text color and underline (because the text is inside <a> tags). So you could add the following style:
ul li a {
   color:Black;
   text-decoration:none;
}

Answer (score 0):

you have to put this in the:

```
a{
  float:left;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding;5px;
}
```

edited:

to put it to the center you have to give the container a width, 315px for example here, but put it in % or em better
....and add a padding to `a`

```
div {
    width:315px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: This worked except now the words are scrunched together and aligned left, like this: http://i.imgur.com/kj4OYkL.jpg

Comment: I was able to fix it with the following code:

    a{float:left;
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-left:170px;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

Thank you!